# How to execute shell script by double clicking in centos?

Tags: centos, sh, gnome

As the tile,I have a shell script needs to run every time I have to open a terminal and type "./ xxx.sh"  .it is annoying when it gets too frequent now how do I execute by double clicking like the way you do it in windows?

I know there is an option just for that in Ubuntu but I can't see that here in CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little bit of digging up and found these two links. Let me know if they were helpful
https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189777/how-to-launch-shell-script-with-double-click-in-centos-7

The first link is an askUbuntu link I know. But gnome uses nautilus as the file explorer program.

In my arch linux installation where I am running a cinnamon desktop environment, I just had to add a shebang (#!/usr/bin/bash) at the head of the file and use `chmod` to make the file an executable and I could run the script from by double clicking on it. I hope you have already tried this?

Comment: The second link you give me have the answer,thank you.I cant open Nautilus in terminal it give error message don't know why

Answer (score 1):

For the record this is how I do it:
In terminal

```
[youname@localhost ~]$ gedit ~/Desktop/YourApplication.desktop
```

In the file

```
    [Desktop Entry]
Name=My Application
Comment=My Application run script
Exec=/AddressOfyourScript/yourscript.sh
Icon=/AddressOfyourIcon/youricon.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

save and done.Apparently CentOS should give a GUI for this function.